# Query with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

i have a problem with a query. I use T-SQL.

I have write this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*),
        MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
FROM    AA_V_MONITOR_RisultatiEserciziR MR
        INNER JOIN AA_V_TER_TerapieRiabilitative TT
            ON MR.IDTerapia = TT.ID
WHERE   MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo IN ( 9, 10, 14 )
        AND TT.CodiceFiscaleAssistito IN ('RICCARDINOFUFFOL')
        AND MR.DATAESECUZIONE >= '2012-01-01'
        AND MR.DataEsecuzione <= '2013-12-12'
GROUP   BY MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
```

i have this result:

```
count(*)    IdEsercizioRiabilitativo
2            10
1            11
1            14
```

This result it's ok but i would like the number of row. I would like to retrieve the number of IDESERCIZIORIABILITATIVO.

I would like to count the number of IdEsercizioRiabilitativo.

In the sample i should to retrieve a number 3.

IdEsercizioRiabilitativo 10,11,14. There are three distinct IdEsercizioRiabilitativo

I don't use a Java,C++ or other but i develop a StoreProceedure

so i have modify my query in

```
SELECT count()
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT()
        ,MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
    FROM AA_V_MONITOR_RisultatiEserciziR MR
    INNER JOIN AA_V_TER_TerapieRiabilitative TT ON MR.IDTerapia = TT.ID
    WHERE MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo IN (
            9
            ,10
            ,14
            )
        AND TT.CodiceFiscaleAssistito IN ('RICCARDINOFUFFOL')
        AND MR.DATAESECUZIONE >= '2012-01-01'
        AND MR.DataEsecuzione <= '2013-12-12'
    GROUP BY MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
    )
```

but i have this response

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Sintassi non corretta in prossimità
>   di ')'.

You can help me?

Thanks to all

Comment: what do you mean by *retrieve the number of IDESERCIZIORIABILITATIVO*

Comment: what is IDESERCIZIORIABILITATIVO , confusing :(

Comment: @Michele delete your answers; they are simply comments or edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

Use @@ROWCOUNT attribute to know what is the number of rows retrieved from the query.

If you are using Java JDBC api.. then you have resultSet.last() and resultSet.getRowNum(). These two methods are subjected to support by jdbc drivers and underlying database

Comment: thanks to all,

i have solved my problem. I have use @@RoCount in my SP.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

What if you use an other COUNT()

> select count(***) from ((SELECT COUNT(*),MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo FROM FOO) as derivedTable)

Of course you have to change the derivedTable request, or just do another request and use a DISTINCT clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as TOT
        ,MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
    FROM AA_V_MONITOR_RisultatiEserciziR MR
    INNER JOIN AA_V_TER_TerapieRiabilitative TT ON MR.IDTerapia = TT.ID
    WHERE MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo IN (
            9
            ,10
            ,14
            )
        AND TT.CodiceFiscaleAssistito IN ('RICCARDINOFUFFOL')
        AND MR.DATAESECUZIONE >= '2012-01-01'
        AND MR.DataEsecuzione <= '2013-12-12'
    GROUP BY MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo
    ) temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be simpler:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo)
FROM    AA_V_MONITOR_RisultatiEserciziR MR
        INNER JOIN AA_V_TER_TerapieRiabilitative TT
            ON MR.IDTerapia = TT.ID
WHERE   MR.IDEsercizioRiabilitativo IN ( 9, 10, 14 )
        AND TT.CodiceFiscaleAssistito IN ('RICCARDINOFUFFOL')
        AND MR.DATAESECUZIONE >= '2012-01-01'
        AND MR.DataEsecuzione <= '2013-12-12'
```